# How to type a function that accepts different types which have some properties in common

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have 2 types which have one property, `myProp`, which is the same:

```
type TypeA = {
  myProp: number;
  propA: string;
}
type TypeB = {
  myProp: number;
  propB: string;
}
```

I want to create a function, `topMyProp`, that can be given an array of either `TypeA` or `TypeB` and that returns the list of items whose value of `myProp` is higher than a threshold, like this:

```
function topMyProp(items: any[], threshold: number) {
  return items.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val > threshold) acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, [])
}
```

This code works, but is not typed and loses any notion about `TypeA` or `TypeB`.

To add typing info, I have tried adding a generic type like this:

```
function topMyProp<T>(items: T[], threshold: number)
```

but this does not work because it does not communicate the fact that `T` has to have `myProp` as property.

I have also tried this:

```
function topMyProp(items: {myProp: number}[], threshold: number)
```

but in this case `topMyProp` returns `{myProp: number}[]` and I lost the information about whether items were of `TypeA` or `TypeB`.

Which is the right way to add types in such a situation?

**SOLUTION**

The solution is the one suggested by the comment of @jonrsharpe

```
function topMyProp<T extends {myProp: number}>(items: T[], threshold: number) {
  return items.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val > threshold) acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, [] as T[])
}
```

Comment: Can you do inheritance with your types?

Comment: @Jeppe I am not sure inheritance would fully solve the problem. I can say that `TypeA` and `TypeB` share the same inherited type, but the function would still return the inherited type and not the exact type used as input

Comment: `T extends {myProp: number}`? Or extract a base type to extend.

Comment: Try this tsplay.dev/WJ8grN

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is close: what the function needs to know is that what will be passed in as `items` is an array of objects that contain that property you need. As suggested in the comments, you can use `T extends {myProp: number}` to add the information that the object will *not only* contain that property. If you at some point need specific information on which type it is exactly, you can make a type guard function.

An alternative would be to write an interface that describes the common properties and have your types inherit from it:

```
interface MyProp {
  myProp: number;
}

interface TypeA extends MyProp {
  propA: string;
}

interface TypeB extends MyProp {
  propB: string;
}

function topMyProp(items: MyProp[], threshold: number) {
  // ...
}
```

Yet another alternative would be to use a type union `TypeA | TypeB` instead, but all these options accomplish the same.

You can't have an annotation that will accept more than one type and yet return exactly the type that was used, because Typescript is a precompiler: the runtime code will be Javascript, and will have no information on types. You're essentially asking TS to give you a function that accepts and gives back both one and two types at the same time.
If you want to ensure that whatever comes out of `topMyProp()` is a specific type, you'll have to make a type guard:

```
function isTypeA(obj: any): obj is TypeA {
  return "PropA" in obj
}
```

and use it anywhere you get a more general type that you need to ensure is more specific.